# How can my library's RecyclerView let its clients customize how rows are rendered?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let's say I've created an android library that exports a fragment that displays notes in a RecyclerView. This library has its own default implementation of a layout to render notes in the RecyclerView, but it wants to allow any clients who use it to customize how the notes are rendered.

Is there a way to design doing this? To somehow create a method that clients can call that has a Note object as a parameter and tells the client to return the view they want to display? If so, how would it work/be called with regards to the Adapter?

Apologies that this post is a little low on details, but I don't know what else to conclude. If there are any follow up questions I'd be glad to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let the user set a custom adapter on the fragment instance, by adding a `setAdapter` method to your fragment.

Or, you could create an optional callback that allows users to customize the creation of note view holders. Here's an example:

```
class NoteFragment : Fragment(), NoteAdapter {

    private val notes = mutableListOf<Note>()

    // This is used to resolve the note adapter from the calling activity or fragment,
    // or if none is found, use the default note adapter.
    private val noteAdapter: NoteAdapter
        get() = (parentFragment as? NoteAdapter)
            ?: (targetFragment as? NoteAdapter)
            ?: (activity as? NoteAdapter)
            ?: this

    // This method provides the default view holder used for note items.
    override fun createNoteViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) =
        DefaultNoteViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_note_view, parent, false))

    abstract class NoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        /** In this method, the view holder views should be bound with the information of the [note]. */
        abstract fun bind(note: Note)
    }

    private inner class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            return noteAdapter.createNoteViewHolder(inflater, parent)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, pos: Int) {
            holder.bind(notes[pos])
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = notes.size
    }

    class DefaultNoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : NoteViewHolder(itemView) {
        override fun bind(note: Note) {
            // Default view binding
        }
    }
}

/** Interface to be implemented by the calling activity or fragment. */
interface NoteAdapter {
    fun createNoteViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup): MyFragment.NoteViewHolder
}

data class Note(val message: String)
```

The fragment tries to find a `NoteAdapter` from the calling activity or fragment first, then if it fails, it uses the default implementation, which is provided by the fragment itself since it implements the `NoteAdapter` interface.

Here's how someone using the fragment from an activity would customize the binding of a note item:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NoteAdapter {

    // ...

    override fun createNoteViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup)
        = CustomNoteViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_note_view, parent, false))

    class CustomNoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : NoteViewHolder(itemView) {
        override fun bind(note: Note) {
            // Custom view binding behavior
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that if the fragment and the activity get recreated on configuration change for example, the fragment will still be able to resolve the adapter on the calling activity without needing to do anything.

Comment: awesome answer! Thank you